# Mongodb: use $sample after $group

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the following data set:

```
{company:"One",  employee:"John"},
{company:"One",  employee:"Mike"},  
{company:"One",  employee:"Donald"},  
{company:"One",  employee:"Mickey"},  
{company:"Two",  employee:"Johnny"},  
{company:"Two",  employee:"David"},
```

Ideally, I want a query that returns all distinct companies, number of employees for each company, random employee for each company

```
{Company: "One" , employee_count=4, randomemployee="Donald"},
{Company: "Two" , employee_count=2, randomemployee="David"},
```

I do find a way to get company and employee_count using aggregate/group
However I don't find a way to add the randomemployee with the same query.

My aggregation:

```
function aggr (collection,cb){
   collection.aggregate(([{$group:{_id:'$company',total:{$sum:1}}},{$sort:{total:-1}}]),function(err, l1){
   cb(null, l1)
})
}
```

I began an other Sample function:

```
function onesample (collection,arg,cb){
    collection.aggregate(([{ $match: { "company": arg }},{ $sample: { size: 1 }}]),function(err, item){
   cb(null, item[0].employee)
})
}
```

But i'm loosing myself with callbacks and loop.
Any elegant way to do this within one query?

Thanks a lot.

following your answer, I tried the following code.
I have an issue with the callback of async.foreachof, seems it doesn't finish before leaving to next step: any clue?

```
var async = require("async");   
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/eyc0';



async.waterfall ([
     function(cb) { 
            MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            cb(null,db)
             })
    },
     function (db, cb) {
             db.collection('kodes', function(err, coll) {
            cb(null,db,coll)
             })
    },
      function (db,coll, cb) {
                 var pipeline = [
                {"$group": {"_id": "$ouat","total": { "$sum": 1}}},
                {"$sort":{"total":-1} },
                {"$project":{"_id": 0,"total":1,"company": "$_id"}}];

                coll.aggregate(pipeline).toArray(function(err, dlist){
                cb(null,db,coll,dlist)
                })
    },
        function (db,coll,dlist, cb) {
            // console.log(dlist)
            cb(null,db,coll,dlist)
    },
          function (db,coll,dlist, cb) {
             var dlist2 = []
                async.forEachOf( 
                    dlist,
                    function(item, key, cb){
                        var pipeline = [{ "$match": { "ouat": item.company } },{ "$sample": { size: 1 } }];
                        coll.aggregate(pipeline, function (err, data) {
                        item["randref"] = data[0].code;
                        console.log(item.company)
                        dlist2.push(item)
                        cb()
                    });

                    }
                );
                 cb(null,db,coll,dlist,dlist2);

    },
        function (db,coll,dlist,dlist2, cb) {
            console.log(dlist2)
            console.log(dlist)
    },
    ])
```

Comment: How do you get `randomemployee`?

Comment: I try to use $sample: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one approach that involves one query, it could be close but not as performant (as it uses **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)**) and won't give you the desired result (only the filtered company):

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$company",
            "total": { "$sum": 1 },
            "employees": { "$push": "$employee" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "company": "$_id",
            "employee_count": "$total"
            "randomemployee": "$employees"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$randomemployee" },
    { "$match": { "company": arg } },
    { "$sample": { size: 1 } }
];
collection.aggregate(pipeline, function(err, result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

However, for a solution that uses callbacks from multiple queries, this can be handled easily with use of **[async](https://github.com/caolan/async)** module.

To get all distinct companies, number of employees for each company, random employee for each company consider using the **[`async.waterfall()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfalltasks-callback)** function where the first task returns the aggregation results with all distinct companies and number of employees for each company.

The second task uses the results from taks 1 above to iterate over using **[`async.forEachOf()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#forEachOf)**. This allows you to perform an asynchronous task for each item, and when they're all done do something else. With each document from the array, run the aggregation operation that uses the **[`$sample`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/)** operator to get a random document with the specified company. With each result, create an extra field with the random employee and push that to an array with the final results that you can access at the end of each task.

Below shows this approach:

```
var async = require("async");    
async.waterfall([

        // Load full aggregation results (won't be called before task 1's "task callback" has been called)
        function(callback) {
            var pipeline = [
                {
                    "$group": {
                        "_id": "$company",
                        "total": { "$sum": 1 }                      
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$project": {
                        "_id": 0,
                        "company": "$_id",                      
                        "employee_count": "total"
                    }
                }
            ];
            collection.aggregate(pipeline, function(err, results){
                if (err) return callback(err);
                callback(results);
            });
        },

        // Load random employee for each of the aggregated results in task 1
        function(results, callback) {
            var docs = []
            async.forEachOf(                
                results,
                function(value, key, callback) {                    
                    var pipeline = [                                
                        { "$match": { "company": value.company } },
                        { "$sample": { size: 1 } }
                    ];
                    collection.aggregate(pipeline, function (err, data) {
                        if (err) return callback(err);
                        value["randomemployee"] = data[0].employee;
                        docs.push(value);
                        callback();
                    });
                },
                function(err)
                    callback(null, docs);
                }
            );
        },
    ], function(err, result) { 
        if (err) return next(err);            
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
    }
);
```

---

With the the **[`async.series()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback)** function, this is useful if you need to execute a set of async functions in a certain order.

Consider the following approach if you wish to get the all the distinct companies and their employee count as one result and the other random employee as another:

```
var async = require("async"),
    locals = {},
    company = "One";
async.series([
        // Load random company
        function(callback) {
            var pipeline = [                                
                { "$match": { "company": company } },
                { "$sample": { size: 1 } }
            ];
            collection.aggregate(pipeline, function(err, result){
                if (err) return callback(err);                
                locals.randomcompany = result[0];
                callback();
            });            
        },
        // Load full aggregation results (won't be called before task 1's "task callback" has been called)
        function(callback) {
            var pipeline = [
                {
                    "$group": {
                        "_id": "$company",
                        "total": { "$sum": 1 }                      
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$project": {
                        "_id": 0,
                        "company": "$_id",                      
                        "employee_count": "total"
                    }
                }
            ];
            collection.aggregate(pipeline, function(err, result){
                if (err) return callback(err);                
                locals.aggregation = result;
                callback();
            });
        }
    ], function(err) { //This function gets called after the two tasks have called their "task callbacks"
        if (err) return next(err);
        //Here locals will be populated with 'randomcompany' and 'aggregation'
        console.log(JSON.stringify(locals, null, 4));
    }
);
```

---

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I clarified the expected results:"I want a query that returns all distinct companies, number of employees for each company, random employee for each company".

Comment: @LittleBigFrog I've updated my answer with another approach.

Comment: many thanks. may I ask the neccessity to use $project on the second answer? : {
                    "$project": {
                        "_id": 0,
                        "company": "$_id",                      
                        "employee_count": "total"
                    }

Comment: You are expecting documents with this structure `{Company: "One" , employee_count=4, randomemployee="Donald"}` in your results, right? The `$project` operator does just that though it won't be necessary if you are okay with your result documents having the `_id` key as company field.

Comment: The [**`async.eachOf()`**](https://github.com/caolan/async#forEachOf) function iterates the values array, and for each value the aggregation pipeline is executed.

Answer (score 2):

```
db.comp.aggregate([
{$group:{_id:'$company',emp:{$addToSet:'$employee'}}},
{$project:{emp:1,employee_count:{'$size':'$emp'}, 
                 randomvalue:{'$literal':Math.random()}}},
{$project:{emp:1,employee_count:1,
           randomposition:{'$floor':
                    {'$multiply':['$randomvalue', '$employee_count']}}}},
{$project:{'Company':'$_id', _id:0, employee_count:1,  
            randomemployee:{'$arrayElemAt':['$emp','$randomposition']}}},
{$sort:{Company:1}} ])
```

Seems to work!

A couple of results:

```
{ "employee_count" : 4, "Company" : "One", "randomemployee" : "Mike" }
{ "employee_count" : 2, "Company" : "Two", "randomemployee" : "Johnny" }

{ "employee_count" : 4, "Company" : "One", "randomemployee" : "Mickey" }
{ "employee_count" : 2, "Company" : "Two", "randomemployee" : "David" }
```

Comment: it's indeed working, however i wanted to use the newly introduced $sample

Comment: @LittleBigFrog `$sample` would not seem to be a good use case here for what you want to achieve, and adds unnecessary overhead. The better improvement here would be using `$addToSet` rather than `$push` for a "distinct" list of employees. Also it would be better to get the random sample from that distinct list in post processing, rather than trying to force within the aggregation pipeline. Just because you can does not mean you should. And the most performant option is to do this in post processing.

Comment: Blakes Seven is right, I have edited the code replacing $push by $addToSet, assuming that every employee have a different name (which seems natural in this problem)